# json undefined when trying to acces to Spotify API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to obtain an access Token using Client Credentials Flow in the Spotify API. I have the following code

```
let oAuthOptions = {
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(CLIENT_ID+':'+CLIENT_SECRET)
  },
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/callback ',
};

fetch(oAuthOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)  
});
```

I'm getting an undefined json and I don't know why, the ID and client secrets are OK because I've tried the curl with the encoded base and it works.
I've tried using response.body.json(), but it reports an error *response.body.json is not a function*

Comment: what does the response object look like? maybe it needs JSON.parse?

Comment: body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: true
​
redirected: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: "basic"
​
url: "http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }

Comment: This last output looks like the original response object, not the response.json() result  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Comment: Yes, because @hurnhu asked for the response objet itself, but if I do response.json() I got this error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `catch(error)` to the promise to check what happened:

```
fetch(url, oAuthOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)  
   })
  .catch(e => console.log("Error:", e));
```

If the error is *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"* then the response is not JSON valid data. In this case try returning `response.text()` to see the plain text response:

```
fetch(url, oAuthOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
   })
```

In your case, the URL is `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`. It looks like the response doesn't have a CORS policy, so it will be blocked if you call this from an unknown host in a web site.

https://jsfiddle.net/tjan64w8/

Comment: It's the same error: Error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". And with text() it returns the html of my react app

Comment: Ok could you check the `response.text()` output? It looks like the response is not JSON

Comment: Yes. It's the html of my react app. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>´...>/html>

Comment: So you need to set up the URL apart from the configuration in the `fetch(url, config)` call. Actually, it's calling your own site instead of https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Comment: I've tried doing that, but it gives me a CORS error which I don't know how to solve, but I downloaded a firefox plugin and it keeps reporting the same json error.

Comment: That CORS error means you can't call this API from the website, it will be blocked because is not in the same domain (spotify.com). Using a server-side CURL or HTTP request will work. Also, doing it in the front-end could expose your API client secret

Comment: Yeah, but it's only for testing, the thing is that with a plugin that allows cors, it says JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"